# Variables created in a module run via run_module() are not displayed in Spyder's variable explorer

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

I have created a project in Spyder. Two scripts are located in the project:

- `module_file.py`, which contains

  ```
  a = 1
  print('Hello!')
  ```
- `main_file.py`, whose purpose is to run `module_file.py` and contains

  ```
   from runpy import run_module
   run_module(mod_name = 'module_file')
  ```

When running `main_file.py`, 'Hello!' is returned but `a` is not created in the variable explorer. Does anyone happen to know why this is?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html#runpy.run_module), it seems `run_module` runs modules in a separate namespace (i.e. one that's the different from the console). Since what you see in the Variable Explorer is what's present in the console namespace, that's why (I think) you can't see the value of `a` on it.

Comment: Thank you @CarlosCordoba, that answers my question. I better read up a bit on how to properly organize code in Python.